# Contador de de uma subsequencia de strings repetidas em C

Tags: c, algoritmo

Considere uma string composta por várias subsequências.

> por exemplo: cccaaaabbbbxdddddddddaaannn.

A menor subsequência é a da letra x, com apenas um elemento; a maior subsequência é a da letra d, com 9 elementos. Faça um algoritmo para ler uma string e mostrar qual é a letra que ocorre na maior subsequência e o tamanho desta, assim como a letra que ocorre na menor subsequência e o tamanho dela.

*Ex.:*

- Entrada: aaabbbbaa;
- Saída: maior b, tamanho 4; menor a, tamanho 2.

Eu consegui fazer com que o código registre e mostre corretamente a maior subsequência mas no segundo `if` não consigo saber qual a lógica correta para registrar e mostrar qual a menor subsequência de caracteres repetidos.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define n 50

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    char cmaior, cmenor;
    char v[n];
    int i, temp = 1, maior=temp, menor=temp;

    printf("\nDigite a string: ");
    gets(v);

    for(i = 0;i < (strlen(v)-1); i++)
    {
        if(v[i] == v[i+1])
        {
            temp++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = 1;
        }

        if ( temp > maior )
        {
            maior = temp;
            cmaior = v[i];
        }

        if ( temp <= menor )
        {
            menor = temp;
            cmenor = v[i];
        }

    }

    printf("\n Maior: %c, tamanho %d; Menor: %c, tamanho %d\n",cmaior,maior, cmenor, menor);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, note que o seu código possui alguns warnings:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:17:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’; did you mean ‘fgets’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     gets(v);
     ^~~~
     fgets
main.c:19:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for(i = 0;i < (strlen(v)-1); i++)
                 ^
/tmp/ccWK0gqI.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x5a): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

Na condição do laço `for`, você faz `i < (strlen(v)-1)`, na verdade deveria ser `i < strlen(v)` ou `i <= strlen(v) - 1`. Você misturou as duas possibilidades.

A cada iteração você aplica a verificação do tamanho da menor string. Isso é um erro de lógica. Todas as contagens começam com 1, isso faz com que o seu algoritmo incorretamente diga que a menor repetição é de tamanho 1, mesmo que nem exista. Faça o teste:

```
Digite a string: aaabbbbcccccc

Maior: c, tamanho 6; Menor: b, tamanho 1
```

Veja que o algoritmo disse que a menor sequência possui tamanho 1, sendo que não existe nenhuma sequencia de tamanho 1 na string.

Você deve fazer essas verificações **somente quando a sequência chegar ao fim**, que é no `else` do primeiro `if`.

```c
for (i = 0; i < strlen(v); i++)
{
    if (v[i] == v[i+1])
    {
        temp++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (temp > maior)
        {
            maior = temp;
            cmaior = v[i];
        }

        if (temp < menor)
        {
            menor = temp;
            cmenor = v[i];
        }

        temp = 1;
    }
}
```

Por fim, você deve inicializar o contador `menor` com o maior valor possível, assim você garante que a sua lógica vai atualizá-lo durante o loop (senão a condição sempre será falsa quando a menor sequência for maior que 1). O maior valor possível é `n`, então use-o pra inicializar a variável.

Segue o código completo, já com os warnings corrigidos:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define n 50

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    char cmaior, cmenor;
    char v[n];
    size_t maior = 1, menor = n, i, temp = 1;

    printf("\nDigite a string: ");
    fgets(v, n, stdin);
    v[strlen(v)-1] = '\0';

    cmaior = v[0];

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(v); i++)
    {
        if (v[i] == v[i+1])
        {
            temp++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp > maior)
            {
                maior = temp;
                cmaior = v[i];
            }

            if (temp < menor)
            {
                menor = temp;
                cmenor = v[i];
            }

            temp = 1;
        }
    }

    printf("\nMaior: %c, tamanho %zu; Menor: %c, tamanho %zu\n", cmaior, maior, cmenor, menor);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que o `menor` começa já com um número muito baixo, então fica complicado. Da mesma forma que inicializou o `maior` com o número mais baixo possível, tem que inicializar o `menor` com o número mais alto possível, portanto é o `N`. Melhorei algumas no código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define N 51

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    char cmaior, cmenor;
    char v[N];
    int contMaior = 1, contMenor = 1, maior = 1, menor = N;
    printf("\nDigite a string: ");
    scanf("%s", v);
    for (int i = 0; v[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (v[i] == v[i + 1]) {
            contMaior++;
            contMenor++;
        } else {
            contMaior = 1;
            contMenor = N;
        }
        if (contMaior > maior) {
            maior = contMaior;
            cmaior = v[i];
        }
        if (contMenor < menor) {
            menor = contMenor;
            cmenor = v[i];
        }
    }
    printf("\n Maior: %c, tamanho %d; Menor: %c, tamanho %d\n", cmaior, maior, cmenor, menor);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2iKvyT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sgrosxrm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/RepeatedCount.c).

Comment: Legal, obrigado pela ajuda! Realmente a parte de inicializar menor com o menor número foi um erro. Mas mesmo assim quando testo o algoritmo ele não dá o assign correto.
Entrada:
aaabbbbaa
Saída:
 Maior: b, tamanho 4; Menor: a, tamanho 1

Comment: A minha maior dúvida é na menor subsequência

Comment: Informe a string `aaaaaa`, o output será `Maior: a, tamanho 6; Menor: a, tamanho 2`. Informe qualquer string de tamanho 1, o output vai exibir lixo de memória (porque `cmaior` e `cmenor` não são inicializadas)

Answer (score 2):

O seu problema da menor sequência está no loop, se você não modificou conforme o Maniero sugeriu.

Você usa:

```
for(i = 0;i < (strlen(v)-1); i++)
```

No seu caso de entrada a palavra tem 9 letras. Dessa forma que você fez você ta indo até `i < 8`, ou seja, vai no máximo até `i = 7`.

Se quer manter o loop dessa forma, tem que ser:

```
for(i = 0;i < strlen(v); i++)
```